# How to create entites in javascript

Tags: javascript

Simple question maybe, but I'm a bit lost here.
Been googling around for a while, but I can't find any information.
Maybe I'm seaching for wrong information..

So please:

A quick example-code would be great!

How do I create an entity in javascript holdning attributes??

Comment: An entity holding attributes? Like... an object? `var foo = { bar: "baz" };`?

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Are you talking about HTML entities? DOM nodes? Objects in JS?

Comment: Pretty unhelpful with the commentless downvotes, folks.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart - what's unhelpful?  The hovertext for a downvote says "it is unclear".  Two people have said "it is not clear what you're trying to accomplish".

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables And then a message appears reminding you to explain your downvote in a comment. If someone already downvoted and commented, do we need five downvotes within a sixty second window to drive the point home?

Comment: @ShawnErquhart The question is bad. Voting is async. I'm surprised it only has three. Voting it *up* is an inappropriate knee-jerk reaction; this question has no redeeming values. Not down-voting is one thing. Implying it has any quality is disingenuous.

Comment: Not knee-jerk. I voted this up as a thoughtful response to a community problem, the very problem that's caused you to grow accustomed these kinds of dogpiles. This kind of thing almost turned me off to SO entirely when I was early on as a dev. A downvote should always be accompanied by an explanation. If your explanation is extraneous because someone else already said it, then they likely already downvoted it as well. No need for pointless negativity, it's completely unhelpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the term you're looking for is 'object'.

```
var myObj = {
    property      : 'value',
    otherProperty : 'otherValue'
}
```

Comment: yeah, must be it. Got just to little information for a school-project. Maybe the school-assignment was formulated wrong. Or me just to tired.... =)